# XPages Bootstrap Modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, xpages

I have some strange behavior that involves bootstrap modals on my XPages. Perhaps one of you might be able to shed some light on what's causing it.

I have two bootstrap modals:

```
<xc:ccSYS_BS_Modal modalSize="regular" modalAllowESC="true"
    modalAnimated="yes" modalID="newAssetModal"
    modalTitle="Create Asset">
    <xp:this.facets>
        <xc:ccNewDocModalButtons xp:key="modalFooterFacet" />
        <xc:ccNewAssetModalForm xp:key="modalContentFacet" />
    </xp:this.facets>
</xc:ccSYS_BS_Modal>

<xc:ccSYS_BS_Modal modalSize="regular" modalAllowESC="true"
    modalAnimated="yes" modalID="newCompanyModal"
    modalTitle="Create Company">
    <xp:this.facets>
        <xc:ccNewDocModalButtons xp:key="modalFooterFacet" />
        <xc:ccNewCompanyModalForm xp:key="modalContentFacet" />
    </xp:this.facets>
</xc:ccSYS_BS_Modal>
```

These are derived from a custom control with the following custom properties: modalAllowEsc, modalAnimated, modalID, modalSize and modalTitle.

Here is the source for the ccNewAssetModalForm:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">       
<xp:panel id="pnlNewAssetModal">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="assetDoc" formName="tblAsset">
            <xp:this.databaseName><![CDATA[#{javascript:var db = sessionScope.serverPath + "!!" + sessionScope.dbName;return db;}]]></xp:this.databaseName>
        </xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:label styleClass="text-muted" value="Asset Class"
        id="label1">
    </xp:label>
    &#160;
    <br></br>
    <xp:inputText id="inputText1" value="#{assetDoc.AssetClass}">
        <xp:this.attrs>
            <xp:attr name="placeholder"
                value="Enter the Asset Class">
            </xp:attr>
        </xp:this.attrs>
    </xp:inputText>
    <br></br>
    <xp:label styleClass="text-muted" value="Asset Life"
        id="label2">
    </xp:label>
    <br></br>
    <xp:inputText id="inputText2" value="#{assetDoc.AssetLife}">
        <xp:this.attrs>
            <xp:attr name="placeholder"
                value="Enter the Asset Life">
            </xp:attr>
        </xp:this.attrs>
    </xp:inputText>
    <br></br>
</xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

The source for the ccNewCompanyModalForm is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">       
<xp:panel id="pnlNewCompanyModal">      
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="companyDoc"
            formName="tblCompany">
            <xp:this.databaseName><![CDATA[#{javascript:var db = sessionScope.serverPath + "!!" + sessionScope.dbName;return db;}]]> </xp:this.databaseName>
        </xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>
        <xp:label styleClass="text-muted"  value="Company Name" id="label4">   </xp:label>
    <br></br><xp:inputText id="inputText4" value="#{companyDoc.CompanyName}">
    <xp:this.attrs>
        <xp:attr name="placeholder" value="Enter the Company Name"></xp:attr>
    </xp:this.attrs>
    </xp:inputText>
    <br></br>
    <xp:label styleClass="text-muted"  value="Company Code" id="label5"></xp:label>
    <br></br><xp:inputText id="inputText5" value="#{companyDoc.CompanyCode}">
    <xp:this.attrs>
        <xp:attr name="placeholder" value="Enter the Company Code"></xp:attr>
    </xp:this.attrs>
    </xp:inputText> 
    <br></br>
    <xp:label styleClass="text-muted"  value="Clearing Code" id="label3"></xp:label>
    <br></br><xp:inputText id="inputText3" value="#{companyDoc.ClearingCode}">
    <xp:this.attrs>
        <xp:attr name="placeholder" value="Enter the Clearing Code"></xp:attr>
    </xp:this.attrs>
    </xp:inputText>
    <br></br>

</xp:panel>                         
</xp:view>
```

My call to the first modal is:

```
<xp:link escape="true" text="" id="link5"
style="color:#4A4A4A">
<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
<xp:this.attrs>
<xp:attr name="data-toggle"
value="modal">
</xp:attr>
<xp:attr name="data-target"
value="#newAssetModal">
</xp:attr>
</xp:this.attrs>                                
<xp:eventHandler event="onclick" refreshMode="partial" execMode="partial"
onComplete="x$('#{id:newAssetModal}').modal();"
refreshId="pnlNewAssetModal" disableValidators="true">
</xp:eventHandler>
</xp:link>
```

The call to the second modal is:

```
<xp:link escape="true" text="" id="link6"
style="color:#4A4A4A">
<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
<xp:this.attrs>
<xp:attr name="data-toggle"
value="modal">
</xp:attr>
<xp:attr name="data-target"
value="#newCompanyModal">
</xp:attr>
</xp:this.attrs>
<xp:eventHandler event="onclick"
execMode="partial" submit="true" refreshMode="partial"
onComplete="x$('#{id:newCompanyModal}').modal();"
refreshId="pnlNewCompanyModal" disableValidators="true">
</xp:eventHandler>
</xp:link>
```

When I click on the first link, it opens the Create Asset modal and when I save it, it creates **TWO** documents - one with the asset form and the other with the company form.

The ccNewDocModalButtons is common to both:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
 <xc:ccSYS_BS_Column>
    <xc:this.columnOffset>
        <xc:columnOffset mobileDevice="0" tabletDevice="0"
            desktopDevice="0" desktopDeviceLarge="0">
        </xc:columnOffset>
    </xc:this.columnOffset>
    <xc:this.columnWidth>
        <xc:columnWidth mobileDevice="12" tabletDevice="12"
            desktopDevice="12" desktopDeviceLarge="12">
        </xc:columnWidth>
    </xc:this.columnWidth>  
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger alert-danger pull-left" 
    data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" >Cancel</button>    
    <xp:button value="Save" id="button1" styleClass="btn btn-primary pull-right">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" refreshMode="complete" immediate="false" save="true"></xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
    </xc:ccSYS_BS_Column>       
</xp:view>
```

I can't for the life of me see why that's happening. If I hide the second modal and the link that calls it, only one document is created.

Obviously, I'm missing something elementary :) I'd appreciate your assistance.

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems both datasources are submitted. There is an action for a button to saveDocument with var parameter, where you can specify which datasource you want to save.
So I think you end up with 2 save buttons, which are shown conditionally and save a datasource.
Here an example to save a specific datasource

```
<xp:button value="Save" id="button1" styleClass="btn btn-primary pull-right">
<xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
  <xp:this.action>
   <xp:actionGroup>
    <xp:saveDocument var="assetDoc"></xp:saveDocument>
   </xp:actionGroup>
  </xp:this.action>
 </xp:eventHandler>
</button
```

Comment: Thank you, Frank. I was not aware of this property.

Answer (score 2):

You're also not setting ignoreRequestParams on the data sources, so you may get problems editing existing documents (you'll be saving the querystring document instead of creating new ones)

Comment: `save` button type saves all datasources on the page. I would strongly discourage using it. With basic XPages understanding you should be more than comfortable with scripting options for saving a specific datasource. `currentDocument` gets a handle on the closest dominoDocument datasource, or you can use the variable name. The custom control will be replaced on your XPage with its contents, so variable names will work as if the contents were copied and pasted onto your XPage.

Comment: Thank you, Paul. I did not realize that the save button saves all datasources on a page. I've set ignoreRequestParams to true. Forgot about that :)